# I need to access files and printer on a Windows machine on my home network from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, windows

I cannot see or access my *Windows 7* computer on my home network from *Ubuntu 18.04*, but with *Ubuntu 14.10* it works fine.

What may be the difference and how can I change it?

Comment: Have you installed SAMBA ?

Comment: yes, only works on u14

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the IP adress in the adress bar: `smb://IP/` an then you should have acess to your Shared Folders from Windows.

---

You can jump to the adress bar with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd>

For example the adress could be `smb://192.168.0.42`

Comment: i tried that many times the response is "failed to retrieve share list: invalid argument

Comment: i have installed samba as recommended from the beginning on 14 and on 18. 14 works but 18 does not same machine different hdd. i even rewrote 18 to no change. that is why i am asking on this forum. what did someone do to 18 that changed the way it works on the network?

Comment: Do you use UFW firewall ? Turn it off and try. Also, check the file /etc/samba/smb.conf on your ubuntu 18.04, compare it to that on 14.10.

Comment: what is ufw, i did not add any firewall on top of standard install, i also looked and played with the samba conf no meaningful results